# My ATX power supply wont fit my microATX power connectors

Tags: power-supply

My ATX power supply wont fit my microATX power connectors.

I know they are compatible but the square-rounded square shapes aren't fitting properly. How can I make them fit?

Comment: How do you know they are compatible.  Based on your description it doesn’t sound like they are.

Answer (score 1):

You are incorrect in assuming that Micro-ATX motherboards always use the same power supply connectors at ATX motherboards.

Micro-ATX refers to the *size* of the motherboard, nothing more.  Micro-ATX motherboards are backwards compatible with ATX cases in *size*. Micro-ATX motherboards will fit inside an ATX case and their case standoffs will match the motherboard.

Backwards compatibility with ATX power supply units is not guaranteed. As with Flex-ATX and Mini-ITX, motherboard manufacturers will often use the ATX PSU connectors, however due to smaller motherboard size and density, other power connectors may be used to save space.

More information can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MicroATX).

You need to refer to your motherboard's manual to determine which is the proper power supply connector for the make and model of your motherboard.